# Put Button and IconButton components in the same row

Tags: reactjs, button, material-ui, grid, iconbutton

So, I want to display a Button in the same row with an IconButton, they are in a Grid container with the prop `align="center"` and I think this might be what is causing the problem. I am a total beginner in material-ui, I tried multiple things but they didn't work, I need help!

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

JSX:

```
<Grid container spacing={1} align="center">
   <Grid item xs={12} direction="row">
      <Button
         variant="contained"
         color="secondary"
         onClick={this.leaveButtonPressed}
      >
      Leave Room
      </Button>
   </Grid>
   <Grid item xs={12}>
      <IconButton color="primary" onClick={() => this.updateShowSettings(true)}>
         <SettingsIcon />
      </IconButton>
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I hope I left the right amount of code, if you need more just ask, thanks already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to place the `Button` in the same row with an `IconButton`, reduce the `xs` value as 12 is the max value and by giving it 12, it'll take the whole width of the parent. So, give it 6 and also the other item to 6.

```
<Box>
    <Grid container spacing={1} align="center" direction="row">
        <Grid item xs={6} >
            <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary"
                onClick={this.leaveButtonPressed}>
                Leave Room
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
            <IconButton color="primary">
                <Settings />
            </IconButton>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Box>
```

Here is the working demo:
[image: Edit awesome-bash-h8eoq]

Comment: That works, thank you! to bring them closer together I just have to set xs to smaller values or there is any better way?

Comment: grid is an easy way, otherwise, you can use `flex`  for placing items